# how to make wider the google orgchart

Tags: jquery, css, google-visualization, orgchart

can I ask some help.How can I make the google org chart looks wider ? I mean the lines are  stretching to occupy the space of the container something like this picture below.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Added code

```
 var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
                    dt.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

                    dt.addRows(data);




                    var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                    chart.draw(dt, {allowHtml:true, allowCollapse:false, size:'small', size: 'medium'});
```

Here is my google orgchart it's not the same to the picture above.

[image]

Comment: please provide sample code. But looks like you should be looking to use a **min-width** (but it's hard to tell, given such little information)

Comment: @jbutler483,does 2 and 3 nodes will automatically stretched if it have many descendants ?

Comment: I honestly can't say without a working demo/markup. After all, we're programmers and like to read **code** rather than sentences.

Comment: @jbutler483,I added my code now,how can I make my orgchart looks the same to the picture that I uploaded,.The 2 and 3 are wider

Comment: could you possibly post the rendered markup? (right click on your page -> view source). And copy the code relating to that?

Answer (score 0):

set the size in your div tag:

```
<div id="chart_div" style="height: 200px; width: 800px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May i know why have you set 'size' property of google org chart 
to small as well as medium at the same time ?
In your code the `size: 'medium'` property is overriding the 
`size: 'small'` property. 
You can try `size:'large'` property. But it will increase the width as well as height of the nodes of org chart.

If you only want to increase the width of all nodes then 
try overriding the org chart classes :

```
.google-visualization-orgchart-table tr td.google-visualization-orgchart-node div { width: 250px!important; }
```

The above solution worked for me.

Comment: Yo do realize that this question is from 2014, right? You might not get the clarification needed. If you want to answer anyway, you should post your answer without asking additional questions.